# Spring JPA query methods with default value

Tags: java, spring, jpa

is it possible for Spring JPA Query methods on the interface to have default value?

This is the common one:
`Optional<DocumentTypeEntity> findByIdAndStatus(BigInteger id, String status);`

I want the status to have a value of "ACTIVE" (this won't work though)
`Optional<DocumentTypeEntity> findByIdAndStatus(BigInteger id, "ACTIVE");`

Maybe anyone has ideas? custom query is my last resort! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at `Specification`, you can follow these two links:
- https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: thanks @MarcosBarbero, will check on it

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can create two methods:

```
Optional<DocumentTypeEntity> findByIdAndStatus(BigInteger id, String status);

default Optional<DocumentTypeEntity> getActiveById(BigInteger id) {
    return findByIdAndStatus(id, "ACTIVE");
}
```

Comment: This makes the trick

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using @Query. In case you don't need a predicate framework in an application (Specifications, QueryDSL,...), it's just easier.